# SpriteKit: Presenting the initial scene wth a transition

Tags: skview, sktransition

I've created multiple transitions from between my game scenes, so I'm unsure why this code is not working.

In my GameViewController, I am simply setting up my TitleScene to appear as the next scene, but I would like it to fade in. I've done this in my touchesBegan succesfully.

Here is the code:

```
@implementation GameViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = NO;
    skView.showsNodeCount = NO;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    SKScene * scene = [TitleScene sceneWithSize:skView.frame.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

    // Present the scene.
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] duration:3.6];
    [skView presentScene:scene transition:transition];

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use SpriteKit to present the initial scene with a transition because the `SKView` is (by definition) not showing any scene before the initial scene, so from its perspective there's nothing for it to transition *from*.

Presumably, from your point of view, you want to fade into your scene from whatever the user is seeing before SpriteKit gets started — the launch screen of your app, maybe? A common strategy for that is to have the initial storyboard scene contain a `UIImageView` containing the same image as your launch screen, layered on top of your `SKView`. When you're ready to start the game, use `UIView` `animateWithDuration:animations:completion:` to fade out the image view and remove it from the view hierarchy, and your `SKView` will be revealed beneath.

Comment: Thanks @rickster worked like a charm... I added a UIView to the mainstoryboard view and set the color and added the following code

Comment: `- (void)fadeView:(UIView*)view toAlpha:(CGFloat)alpha
{
    view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    
    [UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                     animations:^{
                         view.alpha = alpha;
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
                         [view removeFromSuperview];
                     }];
}`